# How would copy something in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would take the user's input and scale an image by the number they give me, for example when they say 2, the original image is

```
hph
pph
h p
```

and after the image is scaled, it would become

```
hhpphh
hhpphh
pppphh
pppphh
hh  pp
hh  pp
```

What functions could I use to do this? Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean with "image"? The shown "ASCII-art" or a real image file?

Comment: I mean made out of letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

think you're going to end up with a bunch of similar answers but tried to pretty it up as much as I could..

```
n = 2
s = '''hph
pph
h p'''

modified = ''.join([letter*n if letter != '\n' else letter for letter in s])

for line in modified.split('\n'):
    for times in range(n):
        print(line)
```

output:

```
hhpphh
hhpphh
pppphh
pppphh
hh  pp
hh  pp
```

Comment: That helped a lot! Could you explain how this works? I change n = 2 to a user input, but I can't seem to understand what you did in the modified variable. I'm kind of a beginner.

Comment: actually I edited it to make it simpler...not sure why I had the second loop in the modified variable..think I was playing with it and it worked and kept going but it was unnecessary..see below comment for some explanation

Comment: modified is a list comprehension, basically just a loop in one line that outputs a list...it loops through each letter/character in `s` (which is a string) and then repeats it n times... i.e. `'h'*2 = 'hh'`, except for the line breaks ('\n') because we dont want the output to have `n` spaces between lines...so now you have a modified string where the letters have just been repeated n times..the for loops at the bottom split the string by `'\n'` (line break) and prints out each line `n` times...i.e. now we've repeated the letters n times (horizontally) and printed them `n` times (vertically)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you input looks like this:

```
[
    'hph',
    'pph',
    'h p',
]
```

You can use this function:

```
def func(lines):
    return '\n'.join('\n'.join(''.join(c+c for c in line) for i in range(2)) for line in lines)
```

Comment: too complicated

Comment: lmao yours is way more complicated

Comment: @DerekEden yeah :)

Comment: Maybe my code is hard to read because I focus speed :)